# The "Tag Menu" shows "Loading Interesting Tags..." in Tag Info and Stats pages

Tags: bug, status-completed, tag-watching

Like this:

[http://www.imgftw.net/img/225508530.png http://www.imgftw.net/img/225508530.png](http://www.imgftw.net/img/225508530.png)

Comment: confirmed ... will get rid of it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removed from the stats and info tab in latest.